# Aztec barcode encoding library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode

I've been searching for a library that can convert a string to an Aztec barcode for display on an iPhone screen, and I haven't been able to find anything. Anyone know of one?

There are a couple of QR code generators, but that's a different thing. It's integrating with an existing system, so it has to be Aztec.

We have no need to scan or decode barcodes, only to display them.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a good opporutnity to start an open source project of your own. :)

Comment: This looks like a nice easy project too. Got a link to a reference for Aztec codes?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. I only found this one: ZXingObjC (https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC), which works perfectly in the example provided but not when I integrate it in my app. I get the blurry aztec code image, but aztec code scanners do not recognize my code image. In the Readme file from githug says it is only BETA version for the Aztec code part.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a third party library — Aztec barcode generation has been part of the built-in Core Image framework since iOS 8 / macOS 10.10. (It also generates QR codes, Code128, and PDF417 barcodes.) Here's a quick example (in Swift 3):

```
let data = "Xiuhcoatl, the turquoise serpent of the fires".data(using: .utf8)!
let aztec = CIFilter(name: "CIAztecCodeGenerator",
    withInputParameters: [ "inputMessage" : data ])!
    .outputImage!
```

And the image it produces: [image: aztec barcode of aztec mythology]

See the docs for [`CIAztecCodeGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAztecCodeGenerator) for additional options on that filter, and [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185) for general info on using Core Image.

Comment: The release of iOS 8 is 4 years in the future, but thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth giving a new answer to an old question, particularly when there's another new answer promoting what's probably not the best current solution. But if you're still in 2010, I recommend buying Apple stock.